# What is a good example of a hyperspace where the base space is non-Hausdorff?

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $\operatorname{CL}(X)$ be its [hyperspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspace_(topology)). That is, $\operatorname{CL}(X)$ is the set of closed subsets of $X$, equipped with the minimal topology so that the canonical map $$x \mapsto \overline{\{x\}}$$is a homeomorphism onto its image.

[Typically](http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jca/jca01/jca01013.pdf), the base space is assumed to be Hausdorff (or at least $T_1$), so that the closure of a singleton is the singleton itself. However, the definition of a hyperspace is perfectly suitable when the space is not Hausdorff, and surely this comes in handy sometimes.

What is a good example of a hyperspace $\operatorname{CL}(X)$ where the base space $X$ is non-Hausdorff?

Comment: The first example of a non-Hausdorff space that comes to mind is the Zariski topology on an algebraic variety. What does the hyperspace of such a topology look like?

Comment: The more standard format on MO for a tag wouuld be 'hyper-topology'. In case you edit the question, you might consider renaming this new tag (via simply changing it).

Comment: I think people look at this when X is a poset with the topology in which upper sets are open. Then the closed sets are lower sets. 

Comment: @quid: I've never seen it hyphenated. On the other hand, I would prefer the tag 'hyperspaces'.

Comment: @François G. Dorais: thank you for the correction. Indeed, I was too quick here. I thought (in error) the situation is analogous, say, to "weak topology" yielding the tag weak-toplogy (not weaktopology); but it is not, so my comment makes little sense.  

Comment: An easy example. Let $X=\set{a, b, c, d\}$ and $T=\set{\emptyset, X, \set{a,b\}\}$, then $(X, T)$ is a no-Hausdorff space.

Comment: @quid & @François: you both have enough reputation, so please feel free to edit the post to change the tags. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made use of this in some (unpublished) work in connection with a formalism  for  discussing so-called geometric limits  of holomorphic  dynamical systems. The details of the  specific application are not  so  relevant, but I've copied the statement here to  give a sense of how what is essentially  Fell's Theorem yields a useful compactness  statement  that was otherwise  not possible to even formulate  this precisely. Todd and Benjamin's  comments are relevant. What saves the day is the fact that the original  space, while not  Hausdorff, is still sober.

A *holomorphic dynamical system* on a complex manifold $X$ is any collection of open
analytic maps, from open subsets to $X$, containing the identity and all implied
restrictions and compositions. We say that the systems ${\cal F}_\eta$ converge *geometrically* to the 
system $\cal F$ whenever

$$\liminf {\cal F}_\eta ={\cal F}= \limsup {\cal F}_\eta$$
where $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are given by the prescription:

$$\liminf {\cal F}_\eta  =  \{f: f_\eta\rightarrow f \mbox{ for some } f_\eta \mbox{ chosen from } {\cal F}_\eta\}$$

$$\limsup {\cal F}_\eta =  \{f: f_{\eta_\kappa}\rightarrow f \mbox{ for some } f_{\eta_\kappa} \mbox{ chosen from some } {\cal F}_{\eta_\kappa}\}.$$

By $f_\eta\rightarrow f$ we mean uniform convergence on compact subsets of converging domains: that is, the domain of $f$ contains a given compact set if and only if the domain of  $f_\eta$ eventually does. A system $\cal F$ is *closed* if it contains every $g$ such that $f_\eta\rightarrow g$ for some $f_\eta\in{\cal F}$.`

We denote the set of holomorphic dynamical systems on $X$ by $HDS(X)$, and the subset of closed holomorphic dynamical systems by ${\bf HDS}(X)$.

**Theorem**

(1) There is a unique topology on ${\bf HDS}(X)$ such that ${\cal F}_\eta\rightarrow{\cal F}$ if and only if $\liminf {\cal F}_\eta ={\cal F}= \limsup {\cal F}_\eta$.

(2) The space ${\bf HDS}(X)$ is compact and Hausdorff.

(3) If $X$ has countably many components then ${\bf HDS}(X)$ is second countable and metrizable.

The space ${\bf HDS}(X)$ both generalizes and contains the space of closed subgroups of PSL$_2{\mathbb{C}}$ with the Hausdorff-Chabauty topology, but the construction requires closer attention to fine points of general topology. In particular, since the appropriate ambient space is neither Hausdorff nor regular, the proper definition of local compactness is crucial: here it should  be in the sense that  every open neighborhood of a point contains a compact subneighborhood. For any topological space $X$, Fell's prescription yields a compact topological space $Fell(X)$ whose points are the closed subsets of $X$. and which  is $Fell(X)$ is compact. Moreover, if $X$ is locally compact then:

(1) The space $Fell(X)$ is Hausdorff.

(2) ${F}_\eta\rightarrow{F}$ if and only if $\liminf {F}_\eta ={F}= \limsup {F}_\eta$.

(3)  If $X$ is second countable then $Fell(X)$ is second countable and metrizable.

Answer (score 4):

A source of examples that comes to mind is Alexandroff topologies. For example, take the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, and declare a set $U \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ to be open if it is downward closed in the usual order. The closure of a point $n$ is then $\{m \in \mathbb{N}: m \geq n\}$. The poset of closed sets under reverse inclusion looks like the ordinal $\omega + 1$, and if you give this the Alexandroff topology as well (open sets = down-sets), then this will give a hypertopology.

Comment: I hadn't seen Benjamin's comment when I was typing. 